# Do Hutts have a biological resistance to Force manipulation?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

The question [Why was Jabba immune to Luke's powers of the Force in Return of the Jedi?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3950/5184) posits that Jedi Mind Tricks do not work on Jabba because he is strong willed.

This makes a good deal of sense, especially given Ben's quote.

> BEN: The Force can have a strong influence on the weak-minded. You
>   will find it a powerful ally.

In the movies, we also meet Watto who claims to be immune to mind tricks. His quote makes it sound like his entire species is immune, and not just him.

> WATTO : No, they won'ta. What you think you're some kinda Jedi, waving your
>   hand around like that? **I'm a Toydarian. Mind tricks don'ta work on me-only
>   money.** No money, no parts! No deal! And no one else has a T-14 hyperdrive, I
>   promise you that.

[Wookieepedia explains](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Toydarian):

> Similar to the Hutts, Toydarian brains have an unusual composition which made them immune to influence from the Force.

**WHOA, THERE!**

Neither the entry for [Jabba](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jabba_Desilijic_Tiure) or [Hutts](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hutt) mention anything like this. In fact, the entry for Hutts states

> Although not common, Hutts were able to be Force-sensitive.

If one is Force-sensitive, they must be able to be influenced by the Force at some level.

**So what gives?**

Is there any evidence that other Hutts are, or are not, susceptible to Jedi Mind Tricks? Is there a biological component that only the Toydarian entry references, for some reason?

Comment: Is the answer "midichlorians"? Actually, for once I think it might be... :-)

Comment: I think Leia had trouble with using force powers on the Hutt in Darksaber - but I avoid reading that book too often to really remember.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of Wookipedia/Wikia authors making up *&(t and giving faux-explanations that stack generic yet canonically unsupported narrative over very narrow facts :(

Comment: @HorusKol - I vaguely remember something similar in Han Solo trilogy but too lazy to crack them open and check.

Comment: The jedi mind trick only works on unnamed characters :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This passage in Wookieepedia appears to be a gross misinterpretation of information from [*The Jedi Path: A Manual For Students Of The Force*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force_%28real-life_book%29), which is now Legends Canon.

The book mentions both species being "resistant" and "difficult to influence", but makes no mention of any immunity in any way.

[image: page scan]

Answer (score 4):

In the episode of Clone Wars The Hunt For Ziro (season 3), one of the Hutts mentions they TAUGHT their child to resist force mind tricks.  Sorry I don't have an exact quote but it has been awhile since I have seen the episode.  So depending on what level of canon you require, it is taught and not biological for Hutts.

Answer (score 0):

Do not trust the Wookieepedia for answers. Ben was right in Star Wars... the Force can be used to trick the weak minded. Jabba was a crime lord and no fool, so he was smart enough to resist the influence Luke was trying to enforce. Likewise, Watto is probably voicing a stereotype for his people... not a fact.

Comment: If I don't trust the Wookiepedia which uses references and cites sources, why would I trust _user25454_ when you do neither?

Comment: @Daft - He was actually pulling a Jedi Mind Trick on you ... it almost succeeded.