# What makes Watto the Toydarian resistant to the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-phantom-menace

Why did the Jedi Mind Trick (JMT) not work on Watto? There is an excerpt from Wookieepedia which states:

> Similar to the Hutts, Toydarian brains have an unusual composition which made them immune to influence from the Force.

Is this the actual reason? Or is it because Watto has the superior mind Obi-Wan talks about in *A New Hope*?

> BEN: The Force can have a strong influence on the weak-minded. You will find it a powerful ally.

Or is it something else altogether? **What makes the Toydarians special?**

**NOTE:** There is some overlap with [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54827/do-hutts-have-a-biological-resistance-to-force-manipulation) here, but I believe the actual question is quite different in nature, as it's about Watto and the Toydarian race.

Comment: I've found what I believe is the basis of the quote you cited, and it's a gross misinterpretation of the source material. [See here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/109051/5184).

Comment: @phantom42 - I was using the quote from the question I referenced. I don't trust Wookiepedia, and thus the question. The real thinking behind my question was whether in order to be influenced by the force, you must have midicloreans (sp) present ... maybe the Toydarians don't have them? It was something I didn't want to just come out and say, so left that part open ended.

Comment: you cited the quote in my original question, which i asked based on wookieepedia. my point is that i found what the wookieepedia writer based that quote on, and it's a misrepresentation of the source material. there seems to be nothing in any canon that actually says they're immune, just that they're resistant. Not a criticism of your question, just pointing out some new information since you seem to be interested.

Comment: @phantom42 - Very good. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Considering the ridiculously small wings which nonetheless keep the body in the air, the Toydarians may themselves be subconsciously using the force, giving them a natural immunity to force-based manipulations.

Comment: @flq - According to the FAQ which I read, the Toydarians have buoyant gasses in their bellies which give them lift. I would bet the wings are only there for propulsion, not lift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Star Wars databank [article on Toydarians](https://www.starwars.com/databank/toydarian) strongly implies that their resistance to mind-control comes from their mental strength of will. To the best of my knowledge, no mention is made within the main canon (e.g. film, TV shows, novelisations, etc.) of them possession any *biological* defence against Jedi mind control techniques:

> Toydarian are fly-like humanoids, with wings, a snout, and webbed
>   feed. **They are known to be strong-willed and resistant to manipulation
>   through the Force.**

This obviously ties in nicely with Anakin's statement in [AotC](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Attack-of-the-Clones.html) about those that the mind-tricks work on:

> **PADMÉ:** *Are you going to use one of your Jedi mind tricks on me?*
>
> **ANAKIN:** *They only work on the weak-minded....*

Comment: I'm pretty sure Anakin's statement was meant more as a stupid flirting technique more than a 'real' answer, as true as it is.

Comment: @Derek Jabba says the same thing when Luke tries mind tricks on him.  But, yeah, Anakin definitely had an angle to work with that truth.

Comment: @derek - The scene is actually a call back to Obi-Wan explaining the mind-trick to Luke

Answer (score 2):

While it isn't stated clearly, it appears that there's a chance other Toydarians are resistant as well.

In the very first episode of Clone Wars cartoon, Dooku and Assaj Ventress are trying to get their way with Toydarians as far as changing their allegiance to CIS instead of Republic. And in the process, basically gently try to convince them (especially their King) of what they want to do.

If Toydarians were as a species succeptible to mind tricks like Humans, I would assume neither Sith would have even remotely hesitated to use that to get their way.

Comment: I was going off of the assumption that *all* Toydarians are resistant ... I'm looking for the *reason(s) why* they are resistant.